# Swift Convert Measurement Units

Tags: swift, units-of-measurement, measurement

You can easily convert measurements from a given one to the locale measurement as such:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
formatter.unitStyle = .long

let km = Measurement(value: 100, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)
let miles = km.converted(to: UnitLength.miles)
print(formatter.string(from: miles))
```

However, how would you convert from the local unit to a given unit. I tried this and expected an output of "kilometers", but instead I got "miles".

```
let formatterTwo = MeasurementFormatter()
formatterTwo.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
formatterTwo.unitStyle = .long
print(formatterTwo.string(from: UnitLength.miles))
```

The goal is to have a textfield that says "Enter distance in *insert locale unit*"

Additionally, is there anyway to get the local equivalent conversion automatically without specifying a conversation? In the first example I gave, I explicitly converted from kilometers too miles. However, it would be great to tell the system to return me the local equivalent, so I don't have to specify.

Comment: Did you mean `print(formatterTwo.string(from: miles))`?. I got "100 kilomètres\n"

Comment: No what I have is correct. Printing from miles will give you "miles" because the miles variable is a Measurement, not a unit.