# About multilingual adaptation of Arabic language in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way how to convert numbers to Arabic in iOS, and is there any way for the system to do it? And also how to convert Bytes/MB/GB these units into Arabic language.
By the way, the Android approach is as follows.
`DecimalFormat(pattern: "0%").format(value)`

Comment: the most funny things about numbers is that they are arabic already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: The author probably means the Eastern Arabic numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals Here's how you can convert numbers in any language to any other language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668231/how-to-convert-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers-in-swift And this post hints how to convert units: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963264/swift-convert-measurement-units